# How to predict present and absent without class label based on another dataset with class label with present and absent

Tags: r

I have two datasets (point locations): one data set containing point locations of a weed collected from the field and has class label present and absent while the other dataset was randomly generated in the R program. I want to assign class label to the points generated in the R program using information from the field data so that I can combine both dataset to model weed presence and absence. Both the dataset has environmental variables but as said above, the only difference is the  points generated in R do not have class label. I have explored resources from the net but I did not find anything that meets my need. All the machine learning or modelling required labelled classes in both training and testing datasets. So any helping hand would be highly appreciated as am stuck to move forward. Thanks a lot in advance.
[Complete dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0yqg.png)
[Incompplete datset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk4y3.png)
I have included two excel sheets containing data. First sheet contains complete data while the second sheet has PresentAbsent and Code column empty. So I want to fill up using the information from the first sheet

Comment: If you include a data example you are more likely to get help. From what I understand, you are looking to merge the data correct?

Comment: I think you are asking more a theorical question rather than a specific question about R. You want to discover labels in a dataset based on a another. You could use your experimental dataset to discover the pattern or correlations for labels and variables. Split that dataset in a training and validation subset. Train a supervised classification model and use the validation subset to test if it generalises enough. When you get a model that does enough, you can apply it in your synthetic dataset to discover the likely label class.

Comment: @David, thanks for your response. I am not trying to merge per se but trying to use the patterns of one dataset to predict the labels of another dataset and in my case present and absent class.

Comment: @RobertoT, thanks for your response. I think you got my point. I will try to implement your suggestion but wondering if classification will work if my dataset contains empty rows classes, which I am trying to get through prediction

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Simplifying, if you have a trained model with your experimental data and you think it is reliable, you can apply it to your second dataset and assume the outcome (labels) is right. However, there are several assumptions and possible bias that is difficult to explain in this post. Also, there are some other approaches you could apply apart from ML. If you are creating a synthetic dataset in R, if you want it to approach the maximum as possible the real data you can use some techniques like bayesian models or oversampling.

Comment: I think this community is better for this questions: https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks RobertoT. I am still working around the problem. Will try to post in the above community also.